# CSS - Hiding text that overlaps with textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have some HTML code here, which creates a textarea and a nice rectangle with the text 'HTML' at the top-right of the textarea. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chris97ong/frbCC/).

```
<div id="html_text"><h5 style="
margin-top: 17px;
margin-left: 400px;
position: fixed;
color: black;
z-index: 1;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-style: solid;
border-width: thin;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;">HTML</h5></div>

<textarea rows="20" style="
margin-left: 20px;
font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
height: 280px;
width: 460px;
resize: none;
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
position: absolute;
z-index: 0;" id="html_code" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
```

However, I want to make it such that when the user has a long string of text that obstructs the rectangle, the rectangle becomes hidden. How can I do that? Best if answer is in Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Why don't you just have it so its on top of the text (kinda see-through) and when you hover over the textbox it disappears. Basically like in Jsfiddle. Also why is all the style inline?

Comment: @Ruddy Even if it disappears when the textbox is hovered / focused, the rectangle will still be obstructed by the text when the user's mouse is moved away from the textbox or the textbox is blurred. And I am not very good at CSS :D

Comment: You may count the word, if it is going to more than limit, you can hide inner div. (It is not for responsive desing)

Comment: @chris97ong I don't see a way to detect if the text is under the box. It would have to be done a different way. Maybe when the user clicks on the textbox is goes away and if theres text in there it doesnt come back, else it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count the number of characters, and then hide the `div` when the text is coming close to it, and show it again if the text is deleted:

**jQUery**:

```
$('#html_code').keyup(function () {

  var count = $(this).val().length;

    if(count > 52) {
        $('#html_text').hide();
    }

    else {
        $('#html_text').show();
    }

});
```

**NOTE:** Also note that you may change the count-number *(52)* if you are changing the width of the textarea, the font, the font-size or anything else that makes the font different from now.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TheYaXxE/frbCC/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can scan the Textarea for newline characters ( '\n' ) and thus get not only the lenght of the whole text, but the length of the first three lines that can collide with the box.
So if you make sure the length of the first three lines is not over 45 characters, it will force sort of a padding around the box and only hide it if the user puts text directly under it.
You will have to adjust the checked length if you change the size of the Textarea.

Here's a quick example with your html code and a script checking the lines:

http://pastebin.com/MEnDk8bW

[image: Preview]

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in counting the `length` of the `textarea` using `.length`....

use the following... note that the length changes with device width.

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(){

    if($(this).val().length > 100){
        $('h5').hide();
    }
})
```

working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wizam/frbCC/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frbCC/5/)

You can do this by creating this in jquery.

**jQuery**

```
$('body').on('focus keypress', '#text-input', function (e) {
    
    var myLength = $("#text-input").val().length;
    if (myLength >= 40) {
        $("#html_text").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the hide or show properties, Use toggle...

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/frbCC/6/)

jQuery

```
$('#html_code').keyup(function () {
    var count = $(this).val().length;
    if (count > 52) $('#html_text').toggle();
});
```